# locationOfTouch and numberOfTouches

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

hi
I have this recognizer, set with 2 touch, but it returns only one, not two CGPoint

```
-(void)gestureLoad {

UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(numTap2:)];
[(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
self.tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];

}

- (void)numTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"x %f y %f",location.x, location.y);

}
```

as I understand, I cycle the number of touch with these two methods, but I have not figured out how to:

```
-(CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view {

}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches {

}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numTap2, use:

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationOfTouch:touchIndex inView:self.view];
```

where `touchIndex` is either 0 or 1.

Comment: ok perfect, I begin to understand, and instead what you put in -(CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view ?

Comment: just remove those two messages -- you don't need them

Comment: Why make touchIndex 0 or 1? I have googled it quite a bit and can't find what that number represents.

Comment: It's an index.  In his recognizer, he used `setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2` to require 2 touches.  This message gives you the location of a single touch -- you need to pass in a 0-based index to say which one you want.  0 is the first touch, 1 is the second touch. Here is the official documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html  The gesture has a private array of touches, you are providing an index into that array.