# UIPanGestureRecognizer get cords of all touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have added the following gesture recognizer:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *d2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                              initWithTarget:self 
                              action:@selector(ViewDragging2:)];
[d2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[d2 setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[targetView addGestureRecognizer:d2];
```

and the method that get's fired when that event occurs is:

```
-(void)ViewDragging2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    // some point
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:targetView];
}
```

that get's me the point of one touch even though I touch with two fingers. How can I retrieve the cords of the first and second touch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access all the touches using these methods:

- `(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches`
- `(CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view`

They are defined in the base class, [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *d2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                          initWithTarget:self 
                          action:@selector(ViewDragging2:)];
  [d2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
  [d2 setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
 [targetView addGestureRecognizer:d2];
```

and the method that get's fired when that event occurs is:

```
   -(void)ViewDragging2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
    {
      // where touchIndex is either 0 or 1.
       CGPoint location = [recognizer locationOfTouch:touchIndex inView:self.view];
   }
```

check this link
[locationOfTouch and numberOfTouches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5979333/730776)

Regards,
Neil.